# Are batch json-rpc requests not supported with near?

Tags: nearprotocol

When trying to batch json rpc requests like this:

```
[
    {
        "jsonrpc":"2.0",
        "id":"46500000",
        "method":"block",
        "params":{
            "block_id": 46500000
        }
    },
    {
        "jsonrpc":"2.0",
        "id":"46500001",
        "method":"block",
        "params":{
            "block_id": 46500001
        }
    }
]
```

The response given is this:

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "error": {
        "name": "REQUEST_VALIDATION_ERROR",
        "cause": {
            "name": "PARSE_ERROR",
            "info": {
                "error_message": "JSON RPC Request format was expected"
            }
        },
        "code": -32700,
        "message": "Parse error",
        "data": "JSON RPC Request format was expected"
    },
    "id": null
}
```

This is quite confusing since the above request is a valid jsonrpc request according to the spec. Are batch requests not supported on near?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, batch JSON RPC requests are not supported by nearcore JSON RPC implementation. Batch JSON RPC requests can become arbitrary heavy. It is preferred to leverage load balancer to get several requests resolved, so just make separate calls instead of batching them.

I wonder what is your use-case, though. Maybe you want to take a look into [Indexer Framework](https://docs.near.org/docs/concepts/indexer)

Comment: "It is preferred to leverage load balancer to get several requests resolved, so just make separate calls instead of batching them." Could you expand on this? Is it something that is needed to build custom by myself or something that's simple to host?

Comment: Do you run your own RPC node? RPC node has concurrent requests handling out of the box. Near Inc runs a number of nodes behind rpc.mainnet.near.org load balancer